# determine the coordinates where two pandas time series cross, and how many times the time series cross

Tags: python, pandas, linegraph, timeserieschart

If I were to graph two time series, let's say they both have an upward positive trend from left to right, is there anyway to use pandas to find where the two lines intersect and how often?

For example:

**How often do the two time series intersect:** 1

**What are the coordinates of the intersecting points:** approx x-axis: 1955 y-axis: 7

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a quick try using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3,4,5], "B":[0.5,3,1,1,6]})
print df
```

Which gives

```
   A    B
0  1  0.5
1  2  3.0
2  3  1.0
3  4  1.0
4  5  6.0
```

Then use the difference

```
df['difference'] = df.A - df.B

df['cross'] = np.sign(df.difference.shift(1))!=np.sign(df.difference)
np.sum(df.cross)-1
```

You need the -1 for the first row in which the `shift(1)` will return `NaN`